# Same Indegree as Outdegree

Tags: graph-theory

Can someone prove (or disprove) the following? If a weakly connected simple oriented graph, oriented meaning a directed graph where no arcs are bidirected,  has every vertex have the same indegree as outdegree then the graph is strongly connected. If that is the case can we generalize to directed rather than oriented? If that is not the case, I would like a counterexample, and would making each vertex have the same in/outdegree as every other vertex as a more strict condition make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma:** If $G$ is a directed graph where each vertex has indegree equal to outdegree, and $A$ is a subset of the vertices of $G$, then the number of edges going from a vertex in $A$ to a vertex not in $A$ is the same as the number of edges going from a vertex not in $A$ to a vertex in $A$ (i.e. $A$ also has "indegree" equal to "outdegree").

Now take an arbitrary vertex $v\in G$ and consider the set $V$ of vertices you can reach from $v$. Assume this isn't the entire graph, and use that $G$ is weakly connected along with the above lemma to reach a contradiction.

Comment: what is the idea behind the proof to this lemma? Any reference?